# how long do files hang around in temporary://?

Tags: files

I want to offer a file download to my users, and I was thinking of using `temporary://` to store the data. But how temporary is it? When do files disappear from it? Of course, I want to avoid having the file not be present when my user goes to download it jsut after a form submission, and I also want it gone after a while. So when do they go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporary files that are created with the managed file functions are deleted when they are older than six hours, and during cron tasks.

The description for the [FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/constant/FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT/7) reports the following text:

> Temporary files older than [DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/constant/DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE/7) will be removed during cron runs, but permanent files will not be removed during the file garbage collection process.

The value of `DRUPAL_MAXIMUM_TEMP_FILE_AGE` is 21600 (seconds), which means six hours.

Answer (score 0):

**From Admin UI**
You can configure and check that from `admin/config/media/file-system`.

**Using Drush** 
Also can be checked and adjusted using `drush` 
`drush cget system.file temporary_maximum_age`to check and `drush cset system.file temporary_maximum_age 300 -y` (To set the time 300 sec)

Also you can customize the setting with `$config['system.file']['temporary_maximum_age'] = TIME_IN_SEC`
 in `settings.php` file.